# How to pass a lot values into GET request parameters

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, postman

I used spring boot and post man in my project.In controller, i used method get all category look like :

```
@GetMapping(value = "/category")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public List<ReadableCategory> findAllCategories(@RequestParam(value = "filter", required = false) List<String> filter, MerchantStore store, Language language) {
    return categoryService.findCategories(store, 0, language, filter);
}
```

MerchanStore:

```
public class MerchantStore implements Auditable {

private final static String DEFAULT_STORE = "DEFAULT";

@Id
@Column(name = "MERCHANT_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
@TableGenerator(name = "TABLE_GEN", table = "SM_SEQUENCER", pkColumnName = "SEQ_NAME",
        valueColumnName = "SEQ_COUNT", pkColumnValue = "STORE_SEQ_NEXT_VAL")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "TABLE_GEN")
@JsonProperty(

        "merchant_id")
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "STORE_NAME", nullable = true, length = 100)
@JsonProperty(value = "store_name")
private String storeName;

@Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$")
@Column(name = "STORE_CODE", nullable = true, unique = true, length = 100)
@JsonProperty(value = "merchant_id")
private String code;

@Column(name = "STORE_PHONE", length = 50)
private String storePhone;

@Column(name = "STORE_ADDRESS")
private String storeAddress;

@Column(name = "STORE_CITY", length = 100)
private String storeCity;

@Column(name = "STORE_POSTAL_CODE", length = 15)
private String storePostcode;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Country.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "COUNTRY_ID", nullable = true)
private Country country;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Zone.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "ZONE_ID", nullable = true)
private Zone zone;

@Column(name = "STORE_STATE_PROV", length = 100)
private String storeStateProvince;

@Column(name = "WEIGHTUNITCODE", length = 5)
private String wightUnitCode = MeasureUnit.LB.name();

@Column(name = "SEIZEUNITCODE", length = 5)
private String seizeUnitCode = MeasureUnit.IN.name();

@Column(name = "IN_BUSINESS_SINCE")
private LocalDate inBusinessSince = LocalDate.now();

@Transient
private String dateBusinessSince;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Language.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "LANGUAGE_ID", nullable = false)
private Language defaultLanguage;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "MERCHANT_LANGUAGE")
private List<Language> languages = new ArrayList<>();

//some thing fields and get/set methods
```

Language.class

```
@Id
@Column(name = "LANGUAGE_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@Embedded
private AuditSection auditSection = new AuditSection();

@Column(name = "CODE", nullable = false)
private String code;

@Column(name = "SORT_ORDER")
private Integer sortOrder;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "defaultLanguage",targetEntity = MerchantStore.class)
@ToString.Exclude
@JsonIgnoreProperties
private List<MerchantStore> storesDefaultLanguage;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "languages",targetEntity = MerchantStore.class,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@ToString.Exclude
@JsonIgnoreProperties
private List<MerchantStore> stores = new ArrayList<>();

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}
```

When i request from postman looklike: 
  http://localhost:8585/api/v1/id=1&storeName=2&code=3&languages=1,2,3

It work but because my class MerchanStore have a lot fields when i request all fields. Example : 10 field , my url very long and complex.
I have two question:

- Is there a better way to post the param without putting it on
     the url using GET request(not Post Request).
- When i put id=1, because class MerchanStore contain id and language
  also contain id, it put same value 1. How to specific value
  MerchanStore with Id and Language with Id.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way to post the param without putting it on the url using GET request(not Post Request).

No. Using GET with request parameters indicates your URL can be **bookmarked**. Especially for searching or filtering purpose, it is very convenient and useful.

> When i put id=1, because class MerchanStore contain id and language also contain id, it put same value 1. How to specific value
>   MerchanStore with Id and Language with Id.

I have no idea for this, maybe you can post it as a new question.

Comment: thank you. But as i write in my post, my object a lot fields. When i put all in url, it very long. When i know, url limit size url ? Is best way do it ? Post something to header or some thing like this

Comment: @trungtbdn11 Yes, URL has maximum length, you can refer to [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers). But most popular web APs also did this such as JIRA, they even use JQL to achieve advanced search with GET method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **@ModelAttribute**..
Try with this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/category")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public List<ReadableCategory> findAllCategories(@RequestParam(value = "filter", required = false) List<String> filter, @ModelAttribute MerchantStore store, @ModelAttribute Language language) {
    return categoryService.findCategories(store, 0, language, filter);
}
```